# Error al implementar código para WhatsApp

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentado implementar *WhatsApp* en mi *WebView* pero me marca un error, en la siguiente parte del código, concretamente en el `return false`:

```
if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
  return false;
}
```

Aqui el código entero por si es que me dejó algun símbolo en algun lado o algo:

```
  myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      boolean overrideUrlLoading = false;
      if (url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {

        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        overrideUrlLoading = true;
      }else {
        view.loadUrl(url);
      }
      return overrideUrlLoading;

      if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
        return false;
      }

      //Agregar validación para email y telefono.
      if( url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") ) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
      }
      return true;
    }
  });
  myWebView.loadUrl("https://midominio.es");
}
```

Nose algo falla o hago mal porque se cierra la app. Ahora junte la parte de whatsapp con lo de tel y mail to para que quede mejor como me comentas....pero algo me dejo

```
   myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        boolean overrideUrlLoading = false;

        if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
            return false;
        }

        //Agregar validación para email y telefono.
        if( url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") ||(url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://"))  ) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            overrideUrlLoading = true;


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return true;

    }
});
myWebView.loadUrl("https://midominio.es");
```

}

Comment: Cuál es el error que te marca?

Comment: unreachable statement y una linea roja por debajo

Comment: @JesusGuillen Debes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/318850/edit) indicando cuál es el error, no dejarlo en un comentario. Para los errores o advertencias se puede usar el signo mayor `> error`, así sale en amarillo.

Comment: Vale gracias ya lo hice

Answer (score 1):

*unreachable statement* te indica que no hay un camino dentro del programa que lleve a que se ejecute esa línea porque el programa, por cualquier camino que tome, termina antes.

En tu caso se debe a:

```
return overrideUrlLoading;
```

Ahí termina el programa.
Lo que viene abajo de esa línea nunca se puede llegar a ejecutar.

Comment: osea entonces ese return overrideUrlLoading; debería ponerlo abajo de todo lo demas? porque probe a quitarlo pero no me inicia whatsapp, se cierra la app

Comment: En lugar de varios return, usa uno solo al final. Usa la variable `overrideUrlLoading` para almacenar el valor a devolver (incluso donde ahora tenes diferentes return(s)), y  acomodá el codigo en los diferentes if-else para que se ejecute solo que tiene que ejecutarse con cada condición.